# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk' only in visual studio code

Tags: python

I am not able to import nltk module only when using visual studio code "play button". I am not using any virtual environment. I can import it when I use the command python3 script.py in terminal.

I checked with a simple script and hope it may be related to the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Visual Studio is not using the right python3 version. You can check your default python3 version by running the following command in the terminal: `python3 --version`

This is the version you're package will be installed to when running a pip install cmd.

On Visual Studio, on the bottom right of the window, click on the Python version. You will see the list of python interpreter available on your machine, make sure you're using the right one.

[image]

[image]